# Path find algorithm for unsorted array of nodes

Tags: sorting, graph-algorithm, path-finding, maze

Scenario:
I have a map of nodes witch are connected together.

- I have unsorted array of all nodes.
- I have function to check if nodes are connected to each other (if node1 is connected to node2).

`function areNodesConnected(node1, node2) return true/false;`

Request:
I am looking for algorithm (pseudocode) to find path between of 2 random nodes using this function.

The result should be sorted array of nodes from node1 at start and node2 at end of array. If there is no path between 2 nodes, then return null.

Notes:

- no need to have shortest route possible
- if there are more path, pick first possible

Thank you for your suggestions. 
I am not requesting full on solution, but pointers where to start solving this problem.

Comment: How about saving all the connected nodes from each node first, then starting from the first random node, start moving to every other connected node and keeping the track of nodes traversed in each path. If a node is repeated, stop your recursion, otherwise do the same for the current node. When the second random node is reached, return the path.

Answer (score 1):

We can use DFS (Depth-first search) to find the answer.

Lets maintain a stack and a visited array to keep track of previously visited nodes. We also need to keep track of each nodes parent for the final answer. Check for edges by using the function areNodesConnected(node1, node2) as described above.

**Steps**

1. Create a stack, parent array, and visited array.
2. Push starting node to stack.
3. While stack is not empty: pop the stack and push all nodes connected to the popped node onto the stack. (with function areNodesConnected) Keep track of where the node came from with the parent array.
4. Iterate over the parent array for the final answer.

**Pseudocode**

```
function findPath(int start, int end, int nodes):
    stack = Stack
    parent = array of integers to keep track of parents, set every value to -1 to start with
    vis = visited array of booleans to keep track of previous nodes

    stack.push(start)
    parent[start] = start // setting the starts parent to itself so we know when to stop searching.

    while stack is not empty:
        int x = stack.pop()
        for y in range 0 to nodes:
            if areNodesConnected(x, y) and not vis[y]: // checking if there is an edge from x to y
                stack.push(y)
                parent[y] = x; // store the parent of y
        vis[x] = true

    // now we have to print our final answer

    if parent[i] == -1:
        return null // there is no path

    list = List for final answer    

    for (int i = end; parent[i] != i; i = parent[i]): // recursively set i to it's parent until it is the starting node.
        list.add(i)

    // now lets add start
    list.add(start)

    return list
```

The only problem with the above solution is that the list is reversed from what you wanted.